# Find how many numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> How many numbers consist of $4$ digits $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such
>   that
>
> $$a\leq b\leq c\leq d$$

a is thousands, b is hundreds, c is tens, and d is unit

What i'm thinking is $6 \times6\times 6\times 6$, but it's wrong.

The multiple choice is :

a) $495$ numbers

b) $385$ numbers

c) $275$ numbers

d) $165$ numbers

e) $55$ numbers

Which one is the answer?

Comment: Is $a$ the leftmost digit?  Can $a$ be zero?  The question is unclear.

Comment: i think it's clear, cz  there is no thousands that start from zero

Comment: It is not clear because we don't know whether your number is of the form $\overline{abcd}$ or $\overline{dcba}$ or any permutation thereof.  In the first case $(a,b,c,d)=(0,1,2,3)$ is not allowed, but in the second case this tuple is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following table.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 9&9&9&9&\color{blue}9\\\hline 8&8&8&8&8\\\hline 7&7&7&7&7\\\hline 6&6&6&6&6\\\hline 5&5&5&5&5\\\hline4 &4&4&4&4\\\hline 3&3&3&3&3\\\hline 2&2&2&2&2\\\hline 1&1&1&1&1\\\hline \color{red}0&0&0&0&0 \\\hline\end{array}$$

We start at the square with the red zero and we want to get to the square with the blue nine.  At each step, we can only walk one step to the right or one step in the upwards direction.  Let $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ be the labels of the last squares we stay in the first column, the second column, the third column, and the forth column respectively.

If $R$ denotes a step that we walk to the right and $U$ denotes a step that we walk upwards, then we can identify our walk with a sequence of $4$ $R$s and $9$ $U$s.  For example, $RUUURRUUUURUU$ gives $(a,b,c,d)=(0,3,3,7)$.  Likewise, $UURURUUUUURUR$ gives $(a,b,c,d)=(2,3,8,9)$.

If $a$ is allowed to be $0$, the first step can be anything.  Therefore, the job can be done in 
$$\frac{(4+9)!}{4!9!}=\frac{13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=715$$ ways.  If $a$ cannot be $0$, then the first step must be $U$.  Therefore, the job can be done in
$$\frac{(4+8)!}{4!8!}=\frac{12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=495$$
ways.

Comment: Fast question please.... what is the idea behind
$$\frac{(R+U)!}{R!U!}$$

Comment: It's permutation with repetition.  You want to arrange $4$ $R$s and $9$ $U$s on a line in the first case.  In the second case, you want to arrange $4$ $R$s and $8$ $U$s on a line in the second case.  See https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations-with-repetition/.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thanks anyway :)